# ¿Cómo convertir determinadas variables numéricas de un dataframe en tipo factor en R?

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe que he importado de un archivo excel, del cual selecciono mis variables de interés y las introduzco en otro dataframe:

```
datos_def <- read_excel("datos_def_excel")
datos_modelo <- subset(datos_def, select = c("SAP", "sexo", "edad","altura","peso", "niv_est","enf_cron","IMC","fuma", "sit_lab",
                                             "frec_act_fis","estrato","ingreso","ingreso_eq","GHQ_12","m2","n_adultos","n_menores",
                                            "ruido", "malos","agua","limpieza",
                                            "cont_indus", "cont_otras","escasez_verde", "molest_animal", "delincuencia"))
```

Todas las variables de este dataframe son de tipo numérico y hay algunas que necesito que sean de tipo factor, así que intento lo siguiente:

```
variables_factor <- c("SAP","sexo","niv_est","enf_cron","fuma","sit_lab","frec_act_fis","estrato",
                     "ruido", "malos","agua","limpieza",
                     "cont_indus", "cont_otras","escasez_verde", "molest_animal", "delincuencia")

datos_modelo[,variables_factor] <- as.factor(datos_modelo[,variables_factor])
```

Sin embargo, me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Error: Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error no lo he podido reproducir, sin embargo no puedes aplicar `as.factor()` de la forma que lo estás haciendo, deberías hacerlo sobre cada columna / variable por separado:

```
datos_modelo[, variables_factor] <- lapply(datos_modelo[, variables_factor], as.factor)
```